Newton Method counterexample Polynomial
Is there an example of a polynomial that converges very slowly with Newton algorithm and very fast with jenkins-traub algorithm?

I don't know the Jenkins-Traub algorithm, but I want to say that you are not going to have a polynomial that has slow convergence in Newton's method at all initial seed values: if the starting value is close enough to a simple root then there will be rapid convergence by Newton's method to the root. Of course "close enough" can be a delicate issue. What this means is that selecting the initial value should be considered part of Newton's method.
Try $f(x) = 1.5 + x - x^3$ and initial value $x_0 = -1$. The unique root is around 1.431.  Starting with $x_0 = -1$, Newton's method bounces around a lot in $[-3,3]$ and it takes about 50 iterations until the recursion starts to quickly converge to the root.

According to Wikipedia the Jenkins–Traub algorithm has a convergence order of $\approx 2.61$ what is slightly faster than the quadratic convergence of the Newton–Raphson method. To compare this figures you should mind the Ostrowski index, which considers also the "drudgery" to achieve a higher convergence order (what is also mentioned in a. m. Wikipedia -- not Ostrowski but "however, it uses one-and-half as many operations per step" as Newton).
